# Rails nested form Validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, validation

I have two models: Owner and Product. I'm creating a form for Product and a nested form in Rails for the belongs_to association model(Owner). I'm using client_side_validations gem to display the validation errors. The validations errors of the Product class get displayed but not of the Owner. This wasn't a problem until the Active Record Validations were to be displayed. So the Validations do work.
How do I get the web page to display Owner side validation errors?

Comment: I tried to add validate: true to the fields_for tag of the Owner but it didn't work. Maybe I should use a different gem?

Comment: Hi Rishab - im having the same issue - did you get a resolution ?